# How to export a .svg with same width as the front-end window

Tags: export, output-formatting, notebooks, svg-format

```
ResourceFunction["CreateSortableUniqueID"][20]
```

[image]

As we see, each row has 2 UUID in the current window. But when I export `.svg` file, I will get a file like this:
[image]
How do I get a `.svg` file to match what I'm showing on the front-end now?

---

I think `Export["file.svg",%,ImageFormattingWidth->Automatic]` should work for me [as the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageFormattingWidth.html):
[image]
But actually it has no effect. I don't sure this is a bug or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Update 2

In the Wolfram Resource System now is available [`ResourceFunction["CellBoundingRectangle"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CellBoundingRectangle/) which can be used to determine the width of the contents of a cell as follows.

First, produce an output cell:

```
expr = ResourceFunction["CreateSortableUniqueID"][20]
```

Adjust the window width of the current notebook in order to obtain the wrapping you wish. Then obtain the current wrappingWidth of the output cell using the syntax `First@CellBoundingRectangle[cellObj, Full, ImageSize]`, and export the expression as `Pane` with `ImageSize->wrappingWidth`:

```
wrappingWidth = 
  First@CellBoundingRectangle[PreviousCell[CellStyle -> "Output"], Full, ImageSize];
First@Import[Export["Output.svg", Pane[expr, ImageSize -> wrappingWidth]]]
```

---

### Update

In [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/270951/280) answer I found a straighforward way to determine the current width of the *output cell area*, which doesn't involve any "magic" numbers:

```
lst = ResourceFunction["CreateSortableUniqueID"][20]

cellAreaWidth = 
  Module[{co, width}, 
   CellPrint[TextCell[Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> {Full, 1}, PlotRangePadding -> None], 
     "Output", CellTags -> "CellAreaWidth", CellOpen -> False]];
   co = First@Cells[CellTags -> "CellAreaWidth"]; 
   SelectionMove[co, All, Cell, AutoScroll -> False];
   width = FirstCase[
     MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`UndocumentedBoxInformationPacket[co, False]], 
     FE`CellWrapper[{__, FE`BoundingRectangle -> {{xmin_, _}, {xmax_, _}}, ___}] :> 
      xmax - xmin];
   NotebookDelete[co];
   width];

Export["file.svg", 
  Pane[lst, ImageSize -> {cellAreaWidth, Automatic}, ImageSizeAction -> "ShrinkToFit", 
   FrameMargins -> None]] // SystemOpen
```

[image: screenshot]

---

### Original answer

To answer the question, we should determine the current width of the *output cell area*.

In [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/270912/280), I developed the following solution, which works perfectly well with *Mathematica* 12.3.1 and 13.1.0 on Windows 10 x64. However, the "magic number" `4` (found for `Maginification -> 1`), which one must subtract from the obtained value, depends on `Maginification` in an unobvious way, and also can be version- and OS-specific.

```
cellAreaWidth = 
  First@Cases[
    FrontEndExecute@
     ExportPacket[
      Notebook[{CellGroupData[{Cell["", "Input"], 
          Cell[BoxData@
            ToBoxes@Annotation[Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> Full, PlotRangePadding -> None], 
              "CellArea", "Region"], "Output"]}]}, 
       WindowSize -> AbsoluteCurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize], 
       Evaluator -> CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], Evaluator]], "BoundingBox", 
      Verbose -> True], {{"CellArea", "Region"}, {{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}} :> 
     xmax - xmin, 3];
```

Knowing `cellAreaWidth`, the direct answer to your question is, according to the Documentation for `Pane`:

```
lst = ResourceFunction["CreateSortableUniqueID"][20]

Export["file.svg", 
  Pane[lst, ImageSize -> {cellAreaWidth - 4, Automatic}, 
   ImageSizeAction -> "ShrinkToFit", FrameMargins -> None]] // SystemOpen
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What's a magic dig....

Comment: @yode I updated the answer with a straighforward implementation, which doesn't involve any "magic" numbers.

Comment: This function(`cellAreaWidth:=Module[]`) is worth writing as a ResourceFunction for the user to call. :)

Comment: @yode OK, I've just submitted `ResourceFunction["CellBoundingRectangle"]`. Hopefully it will be published soon (the usual responce time is 15 days).

Comment: @yode My `ResourceFunction["CellBoundingRectangle"]` is [published](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CellBoundingRectangle/). I've updated the answer with a usage example.

Comment: I note that just now, it is a very utility function. Thanks very much. :)

Answer (score 4):

The output you see in the front end is function of the window width. If you resize the window, it will change. You just happened to have the window sized so that only 2 entries shows before it wraps around.

One way to fix it so that only 2 entries show up in each row is to use `Parition`

```
out = ResourceFunction["CreateSortableUniqueID"][20]
out = Partition[out, 2] // MatrixForm
Export["t.svg", out]
```

This is how the svg looks like in the browser:

[image]

If you do not like `MatrixForm` you can use say `Grid`

```
out = Partition[out, 2] // Grid
Export["t.svg", out]
```

and now it looks like

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In this answer I propose completely another approach, which uses `Dynamic` machinery instead of determining current *output cell area*. It simplifies things a lot and at the same time provides additional flexibility.

Here is a possible setup:

```
lst = ResourceFunction["CreateSortableUniqueID"][20];

windowWidth = AbsoluteCurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize][[1]]
paneWidth = windowWidth - 120;
Manipulator[Dynamic[paneWidth], {paneWidth/3, windowWidth, .1}, Appearance -> "Open", 
 ImageSize -> windowWidth - 120]
Style[pane = 
  Pane[lst, ImageSize -> {Dynamic[paneWidth], Automatic}, 
   ImageSizeAction -> "ShrinkToFit", FrameMargins -> None], Background -> LightBlue]
```

[image: screenshot]

After selecting an appropriate pane width using `Manipulator`, one can simply export the `Pane` without the `Style` wrapper:

```
Export["file.svg", pane] // SystemOpen
```

[image: screenshot]

---

**Controlling wrapping by changing the window width**

If one wish to control the wrapping directly by changing the window width, here is even simpler setup which allows to achieve this:

```
lst = ResourceFunction["CreateSortableUniqueID"][20];

expr = With[{nb = EvaluationNotebook[]},
  TextCell[lst, "Output", 
   CellSize -> {Dynamic[AbsoluteCurrentValue[nb, WindowSize][[1]] - 120], Automatic}, 
   CellMargins -> 0, Evaluator -> CurrentValue[nb, Evaluator]]]
```

[image: screenshot]

After adjusting the window width appropriately, the `expr` can be directly exported with the choosen `CellSize` option value already applied:

```
Export["file.svg", expr] // SystemOpen
```

Comment: Could I know what is your `120`?

Comment: @yode This is an arbitrary number, as well as `3` in `paneWidth/3`. If desired, it can be replaced by any other. I chose it so that the `Manipulator` and `Pane` do not go beyond the visible portion of the `Cell`.

Comment: @yode Added a simpler setup which allows controlling the wrapping width by changing the width of the window.