# How to determine the current width of the output cell area?

Tags: output-formatting, notebooks, options, cells, undocumented

When answering [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/270892/280), I suddenly realized that it is surprisingly difficult to determine the current width of the output cell contents.

I tried to employ the [`ResourceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceFunction) ["GraphicsInformation"](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/GraphicsInformation) as follows:

```
cellAreaWidth = 
 First["ImageSize" /. 
   ResourceFunction["GraphicsInformation"][Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> Full]]]
```

> ```
> 630.75
> ```

However, experimentation by trial and error shows that the returned value is always significantly *larger* than the actual value, what can be due to the following reasons:

1. The invisible `Notebook` window (which `ExportPacket` creates under the hood) has no frame and no vertical scroll bar.*****
2. The `Cell` where the `Graphics` object is placed isn't a member of a `CellGroup`, and hence the cell bracket is single, not double.

Also, I tried to calculate the cell area width from the documented option values:

```
cellAreaWidth = 
 AbsoluteCurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize][[1]] - 
  Tr[Total[AbsoluteCurrentValue[EvaluationCell[], #] & /@ 
       {CellMargins, CellFrameMargins, CellLabelMargins}][[1]]] - 
  Total[{"Margins", "Thickness", "Widths"} /. 
    Options[EvaluationCell[], CellBracketOptions][[1, 2]], 2]
```

> ```
> 617.5
> ```

The obtained value seems to be very close to the actual value. But then I realized, that `AbsoluteCurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize]` returns the full window size, which includes the space taken by the window frame and the vertical scroll bar (and I have no idea how to determine them).***** Also, I'm not sure that the space taken by the cell bracket should actually be calculated as the sum of `"Margins"`, `"Thickness"` and `"Widths"`. And third, the calculated cell bracket width should be multiplied by two, because a generated `"Output"` cell normally has two cell brackets (because by default it is grouped with the parent `"Input"` cell). But in this case I get a lesser value.

So, I'm in a confusion.

**How to determine the current width of the internal area of an `"Output"` cell (which is a member of a cell group)?**

For tesing, I used the following setup (change the window width, evaluate and check whether the contents of `Pane` is formatted exactly the same as the contents of the generated `"Output"` cell):

```
cellContentsWidth = 
 AbsoluteCurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize][[1]] - 
  Tr[Total[AbsoluteCurrentValue[EvaluationCell[], #] & /@ {CellMargins, CellFrameMargins, 
       CellLabelMargins}][[1]]] - 
  2 Total[{"Thickness",(*"Margins",*)"Widths"} /. 
     AbsoluteOptions[EvaluationCell[], CellBracketOptions][[1, 2]], 2]

lst = ResourceFunction["CreateSortableUniqueID"][20]

Pane[lst, ImageSize -> {cellContentsWidth, Automatic}, ImageSizeAction -> "ShrinkToFit", 
 FrameMargins -> None]
```

---

***** According to the Documentation page for [`WindowSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WindowSize.html),

> The setting for `WindowSize` specifies the size of the content area of the window, excluding any frame.

But this statement is clearly false, because when the Notebook window is maximized (using the Maximize button on the window's title bar), its width from `WindowSize` is exactly equal to the width of the `"Region"` of the current display:

```
"Region" /. SystemInformation["Devices", "ConnectedDisplays"]
AbsoluteCurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize]
```

> ```
> {{{0., 1920.}, {0., 780.}}}
> ```

> ```
> {1920., 747.75}
> ```

Checking shows that `WindowSize` doesn't depend on the presence of `WindowFrame`, `WindowFrameElements` and `WindowElements`:

```
ws1 = AbsoluteCurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize][[1]];
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowFrame -> "Frameless", WindowFrameElements -> {}, 
  WindowElements -> {}];
ws2 = AbsoluteCurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize][[1]];
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowFrame -> Inherited, 
  WindowFrameElements -> Inherited, WindowElements -> Inherited];
ws1 == ws2
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Strongly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147217/280

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/158821/280

Comment: Related: "[Obtaining the correct size of notebooks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/153873/280)."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update 2

In the Wolfram Resource System now is available [`ResourceFunction["CellBoundingRectangle"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CellBoundingRectangle/) which can be used to determine the width of the contents of a cell as follows.

First, produce an output cell:

```
expr = Expand[(a + b)^20];
TraditionalForm[expr]
```

Get the current absolute wrapping width of the output cell using the syntax `First@CellBoundingRectangle[cellObj, Full, ImageSize]`, and specify it as `ImageSize` for `Pane`, in order to reproduce the current wrapping independently of the `WindowSize`:

```
wrappingWidth = 
  First@CellBoundingRectangle[PreviousCell[CellStyle -> "Output"], Full, ImageSize]
TraditionalForm@Pane[expr, ImageSize -> wrappingWidth]
```

[image: screesnhot]

---

### Update

I found even simpler way to determine the width of the contents of the `"Output"` cell, which doesn't require creating a new Notebook.

Setting the second argument of `` FrontEnd`UndocumentedBoxInformationPacket `` to `False` results in that it will return information only for current selection in the Notebook. Hence we can get the required information as follows:

```
cellAreaWidth = Module[{co, width},
 CellPrint[TextCell[Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> {Full, 1}, PlotRangePadding -> None], 
   "Output", CellTags -> "CellAreaWidth", CellOpen -> False]];
 co = First@Cells[CellTags -> "CellAreaWidth"]; 
 SelectionMove[co, All, Cell, AutoScroll->False]; 
 width = FirstCase[
   MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`UndocumentedBoxInformationPacket[co, False]], 
   FE`CellWrapper[{__, FE`BoundingRectangle -> {{xmin_, _}, {xmax_, _}}, ___}] :> 
    xmax - xmin];
 NotebookDelete[co];
 width]
```

---

### Original answer

Thanks to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/52402/280) informative answer by [Silvia](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/17/silvia), now I have figured out how to obtain the required information without any "magic" numbers.

First, create a `Notebook` containing an `"Output"` cell with the output of `Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> Full, PlotRangePadding -> None]` as the first cell in a cell group:

```
nb = CreateDocument[{
    CellGroup[
     {ExpressionCell[Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> Full, PlotRangePadding -> None], 
       "Output"],
      ExpressionCell["", "Output"]}]},
   WindowSize -> AbsoluteCurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize], 
   Evaluator -> CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], Evaluator], CellGrouping -> Manual, 
   Magnification -> CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], Magnification], Visible -> False];
```

Now get the width of the contents of the first cell as

```
cellAreaWidth = FirstCase[
  MathLink`CallFrontEnd[
   FrontEnd`UndocumentedBoxInformationPacket[nb]],
  FE`CellWrapper[
    {__, FE`BoundingRectangle -> {{xmin_, ymin_}, {xmax_, ymax_}}, ___}] :> xmax - xmin]
```

For `Magnification -> 1` this code returns exactly the same number as the code in [my previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/270912/280) (after subtracting the "magic" number `4`).

Do not forget to close created Notebook:

```
NotebookClose[nb]
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

Below is one approach that seems to work, apart from being off by the same 4 printers points as one of the other answers. The key advantage is that it returns the actual size of the current output cell and doesn't require any helper notebook.

```
DynamicModule[
 {cellSize},
 Dynamic@Pane[cellSize, ImageSize -> Full],
 Initialization :> SetOptions[
   EvaluationCell[],
   CellDynamicExpression -> Dynamic[
     AbsoluteCurrentValue@WindowSize;
     cellSize = AbsoluteCurrentValue@CellSize
     ]
   ]
 ]
```

[image]

Some notes & remaining questions/issues:

- I am using `Pane[...,ImageSize->Full]` to make force the cell to take up the full width. Any other strategy to make the cell fill the entire width will also work, and if it is removed, the smaller size of the "shrink-wrapped" cell is returned
- What's up with the offset of 4?
- I couldn't get `AbsoluteCurrentValue@CellSize` to work anywhere besides `CellDynamicExpression`, even `AbsoluteCurrentSize[EvaluationCell[], CellSize]` doesn't seem to work
- Some kind of manual force-refreshing is required. What form this takes depends on the application. Above, I am calling `AbsoluteCurrentValue@WindowSize` to make the dynamic expression refresh whenever the window size changes. Of course, this might not catch all reasons for the cell size to change, but it might be a better tradeoff than a `Refresh[...,UpdateInterval->0.1]` style solution.

Comment: Very instructive, thank you! I just found that `AbsoluteCurrentValue[PreviousCell[], CellSize]` works when the `PreviousCell[]` contains the output of `Pane["", ImageSize -> Full]` (and it also is off by 4 printer's points!).

Answer (score 3):

Currently I've developed the following solution, which seems to work perfectly with *Mathematica* 12.3.1 and 13.1.0 on Windows 10 x64. However, I still don't understand from where comes the "magic number" `4` pts, which I must subtract from the obtained width in order to achieve the perfect match. The value `4` was found for `Maginification -> 1`, and depends on the `Maginification` setting in an unobvious way. Also, this value can be version- and OS-specific. It is also strange that without `PlotRangePadding -> None` the code sometimes returns slightly different value.

```
cellAreaWidth = 
  First@Cases[
    FrontEndExecute@
     ExportPacket[
      Notebook[{Cell@CellGroupData[{Cell["", "Input"], 
          Cell[BoxData@
            ToBoxes@Annotation[Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> Full, PlotRangePadding -> None], 
              "CellArea", "Region"], "Output"]}]}, 
       WindowSize -> AbsoluteCurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize], 
       Evaluator -> CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], Evaluator]], "BoundingBox", 
      Verbose -> True], {{"CellArea", "Region"}, {{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}} :> 
     xmax - xmin, 3];

lst = ResourceFunction["CreateSortableUniqueID"][20]

Pane[lst, ImageSize -> {cellAreaWidth - 4, Automatic}, 
 ImageSizeAction -> "ShrinkToFit", FrameMargins -> None]
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Since currently the method demonstrated by [Lukas Lang](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/36508/lukas-lang) is the only documented and straightforward way to get the current cell width (with some "magic" offset), let us investigate how it is related to the `Magnification` and to the actual cell width returned by `` FrontEnd`UndocumentedBoxInformationPacket ``.

First, define an auxiliary function:

```
cellWidth[cell_CellObject] := (SelectionMove[cell, All, Cell, AutoScroll -> False];
  FirstCase[
   MathLink`CallFrontEnd[
    FrontEnd`UndocumentedBoxInformationPacket[ParentNotebook@cell, False]], 
   FE`CellWrapper[{__, FE`BoundingRectangle -> {{xmin_, _}, {xmax_, _}}, ___}] :> 
    xmax - xmin])
```

Next, create a tagged cell containing the output of `Pane["", ImageSize -> {Full, Automatic}]`:

```
CellPrint[ExpressionCell[Pane["", ImageSize -> {Full, Automatic}], "Output", 
  CellTags -> "cellsize"]]
```

With this setup, find out how `cellWidth` and `CellSize` depend on `Magnification` (output is from *Mathematica* 13.1.0 on Windows 10 x64):

```
cellObj = First[Cells[CellTags -> "cellsize"]];
lst = Table[SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Magnification -> i]; Pause[.1]; 
  {i, cellWidth[cellObj],
   AbsoluteCurrentValue[cellObj, CellSize][[1]]}, {i, .3, 6, .1}]
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Magnification -> 1]
ListPlot[{lst[[All, {1, 2}]], lst[[All, {1, 3}]]}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Magnification, "Width, printer's points"}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"cellWidth", "CellSize"}]
```

> ```
> {{0.3,1862.45,6221.5},{0.4,1854.85,4647.13},{0.5,1847.25,3702.5},{0.6,1839.65,3072.75},{0.7,1832.05,2622.93},{0.8,1824.45,2285.56},{0.9,1816.85,2023.17},{1.,1809.25,1813.25},{1.1,1801.65,1641.5},{1.2,1794.05,1498.38},{1.3,1786.45,1377.27},{1.4,1778.85,1273.46},{1.5,1771.25,1183.5},{1.6,1763.65,1104.78},{1.7,1756.05,1035.32},{1.8,1748.45,973.583},{1.9,1740.85,918.342},{2.,1733.25,868.625},{2.1,1725.65,823.643},{2.2,1718.05,782.75},{2.3,1710.45,745.413},{2.4,1702.85,711.188},{2.5,1695.25,679.7},{2.6,1687.65,650.635},{2.7,1680.05,623.722},{2.8,1672.45,598.732},{2.9,1664.85,575.466},{3.,1657.25,553.75},{3.1,1649.65,533.435},{3.2,1642.05,514.391},{3.3,1634.45,496.5},{3.4,1626.85,479.662},{3.5,1619.25,463.786},{3.6,1611.65,448.792},{3.7,1604.05,434.608},{3.8,1596.45,421.171},{3.9,1588.85,408.423},{4.,1581.25,396.313},{4.1,1573.65,384.793},{4.2,1566.05,373.821},{4.3,1558.45,363.36},{4.4,1550.85,353.375},{4.5,1543.25,343.833},{4.6,1535.65,334.707},{4.7,1528.05,325.968},{4.8,1520.45,317.594},{4.9,1512.85,309.561},{5.,1505.25,301.85},{5.1,1497.65,294.441},{5.2,1490.05,287.317},{5.3,1482.45,280.462},{5.4,1474.85,273.861},{5.5,1467.25,267.5},{5.6,1459.65,261.366},{5.7,1452.05,255.447},{5.8,1444.45,249.733},{5.9,1436.85,244.212},{6.,1429.25,238.875}}
> ```

> [image: plot]

We see that while `cellWidth` depends linearly on `Magnification`, for `CellSize` the dependence is purely hyperbolic:

```
ListPlot[{1/#1, #3} & @@@ lst, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {1/Magnification, "Width, printer's points"}, PlotLegends -> {"CellSize"}]
```

> [image: plot]

```
FindFormula[{1/#1, #3} & @@@ lst]
```

> ```
> -76. + 1889.25 #1 &
> ```

Apparently, the offset `-76.` comes from `CellMargins`:

```
Total@AbsoluteCurrentValue[
   EvaluationNotebook[], {StyleDefinitions, "Output", CellMargins}][[1]]
```

> ```
> 76
> ```

Let us find the formula for `cellWidth`:

```
FindFormula[lst[[All, {1, 2}]]]
```

> ```
> 1885.25 - 76. #1 &
> ```

Here we have the known coefficient `-76.` and the offset `1885.25`, which is exactly 4 pts smaller than the coefficient `1889.25` in the formula for `CellMargins`.

Apparently, `cellWidth` and `CellSize` are related by the relation:

```
AbsoluteCurrentValue[cellObj, CellSize][[1]]*AbsoluteCurrentValue[Magnification] == 
 cellWidth[cellObj] + 4
```

It remains only to understand where the values `1885.25` and `1889.25` come from.

Experimentation shows that `CellMargins` depend on `"Margins"` and `"Widths"` suboptions of `CellBracketOptions`, but doesn't depend on the `"Thickness"` suboption, and the formula in our case is as follows:

```
zeroCellWidth - (leftMargin + rightMargin + leftWidth + 2*rightWidth)
```

where `2` is the number of cell brackets (our cell is grouped with input cell). Here is a checkup with random settings for `CellBracketOptions`:

```
SetOptions[cellObj, 
  CellBracketOptions -> {"Margins" -> {0, 0}, "Thickness" -> 0, "Widths" -> {0, 0}}];
zeroCellWidth = AbsoluteCurrentValue[cellObj, CellSize][[1]];
And @@ Table[
  {leftMargin, rightMargin, leftWidth, rightWidth, thickness} = RandomReal[{0, 100}, 5];
  SetOptions[cellObj, 
   CellBracketOptions -> {"Margins" -> {leftMargin, rightMargin}, 
     "Thickness" -> thickness, "Widths" -> {leftWidth, rightWidth}}];
  AbsoluteCurrentValue[cellObj, CellSize][[1]] ==
   zeroCellWidth - (leftMargin + rightMargin + leftWidth + 2 rightWidth), {100}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

In more complicated cases, when we have a deeper nesting, the following formula works (at least, with the default stylesheet):

```
zeroCellWidth - (leftMargin + rightMargin + n*leftWidth + (n+1)*rightWidth)
```

where `n` is the number of enclosign `CellGroup`s containing the `Cell` of interest.

Further experiments show that `zeroCellWidth` for frameless window is equal to window width from `WindowSize` minus `(leftCellMargin + rightCellMargin - 10)`, and the window frame with all elements in my case has width `24.75` pts:

```
windowWidth = AbsoluteCurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize][[1]]
SetOptions[cellObj, 
  CellBracketOptions -> {"Margins" -> {0, 0}, "Thickness" -> 0, "Widths" -> {0, 0}}];
SetOptions[cellObj, CellMargins -> {{66, 10}, {0, 0}}];
zeroCellWidth = AbsoluteCurrentValue[cellObj, CellSize][[1]]
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowFrame -> "Frameless", WindowFrameElements -> {}, 
  WindowElements -> {}];
framelessZeroCellWidth = AbsoluteCurrentValue[cellObj, CellSize][[1]]
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowFrame -> Inherited, 
  WindowFrameElements -> Inherited, WindowElements -> Inherited];
windowWidth - framelessZeroCellWidth
zeroCellWidth - framelessZeroCellWidth
```

> ```
> 1920.
>
> 1829.25
>
> 1854.
>
> 66.
>
> -24.75
> ```

The last value `24.75` pts seems to be too high, because a simple pixel count in the screenshots shows that the vertical scrollbar, including the frame, is 17 pixels wide, and the frame itself is 1 pixel wide. Translating this to printer's points, we get:

```
18*72./96
```

> ```
> 13.5
> ```

This is what should be expected as the value for the width of window frame with all its elements.